Is $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R}, (1+x^2)dx)$?
Is $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R}, (1+x^2)dx)$ ?
It is known that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R}, dx)$. I guess that the above problem has a positive answer.

Yes, it is true and the proof pretty much the same as in the usual case.

Can you please give a sketch of the proof?

It is the same as the standard proof. Cut-off and mollify. Done.

Let $f\in L^1((1+|x|^2)\,\mathrm d x)$. Then $g = (1+|x|^2)\,f \in L^1$ so by the density in $L^1$, there is a sequence of functions $\varphi_n\in C^\infty_c$ such that $\varphi_n\to g$ in $L^1$. But then $\psi_n= (1+|x|^2)^{-1}\varphi_n \in C^\infty_c$ and $\psi_n\to f$ in $L^1((1+|x|^2)\,\mathrm d x)$.

I guess it should be $\psi_n =(1+\vert x \vert^2)^{-1} \varphi_n$, right?

Yes of course, modified
